# How to get path.join in Rust?

Tags: node.js, rust

How do I write the path.join in Rust. I tried multiple examples but couldn't get it.

```
const exeDirectory = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'bin', 'openvpn.exe');
const processFile = path.join(__dirname, '..', '1');
```

I want to convert these lines of JS into Rust.

Comment: Use a search engine in your web browser and enter `rust path join`, you will find [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.join) and [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std_misc/path.html).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. One thing you could do to improve your question is show what you've tried so far, so we can explain why they didn't work.

Comment: @prog-fh I searched that and that's how I ended up here :D

Answer (score 29):

Use [Path](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std_misc/path.html) which has the `.join` method

```
Path::new("..").join("bin").join("openvpn.exe");
```

Comment: Though be aware that each `join()` allocates a whole new `PathBuf` each time.

Answer (score 9):

I may be missing something but have you looked at [`Path::join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.join), and [`PathBuf::push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.push) linked from it?

```
let exe_directory = Path::new(dirname).join("..").join("bin").join("openvpn.exe");
println!("{:?}", exe_directory);


let mut exe_directory = PathBuf::new();
exe_directory.push(dirname);
exe_directory.push("..");
exe_directory.push("bin");
exe_directory.push("openvpn.exe");
println!("{:?}", exe_directory);
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c931b9c9d83b94b985e98f5c11f1112c)

Answer (score 9):

Another option is collecting an iterator of string into a `PathBuf`:

```
let path: PathBuf = ["..", "bin", "openvpn.exe"].iter().collect();
```

This is equivalent to creating a new `PathBuf` and calling `.push()` for each string in the iterator. To add multiple new components to an existing `PathBuf`, you can use the `extend()` method:

```
let mut path = PathBuf::from(dir_name);
path.extend(&["..", "bin", "openvpn.exe"]);
```